# Postgres recovery_min_apply_delay metric

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-10

We have delayed replicas (2h for example) and prometheus monitoring.
Prometheus do the query to get replication lag:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT pg_is_in_recovery() THEN 0 ELSE GREATEST (0, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp()))) END AS lag
```

On delayed replicas it's return replication delay, like 7200 (2h replica delay).
I want to modify this request like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT pg_is_in_recovery() THEN 0 ELSE GREATEST (0, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp() - PG_GET_recovery_min_apply_delay()))) END AS lag
```

But i cannot find how i can get current recovery_min_apply_delay value via SQL.
Someone know how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html

You want `current_setting`, which does what you would expect but returns a text value (because all settings can be represented as text)

Comment: `current_setting` does not work for `recovery_min_apply_delay` (at least with PG 10).

Comment: I don't think that value is in V10. I think it was introduced in v12